# How can I get a multilingual footer text in the WordPress Astra theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, multilingual

How can I get a multilingual footer text in the [WordPress Astra](https://wpastra.com/) theme? I am using Polylang for translation and do not see an option to translate the footer somehow. The theme should be [multilingual](https://wpastra.com/docs/turn-astra-multilingual-with-wpml/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not seem to be possible yet. If someone finds out that it is, just add an answer and I will accept this one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with String translations under Polylang?

https://polylang.pro/doc/strings-translation/

The footer text might be available for translation there.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only see string translations for the date and time formats, the subtitle and the cookie notice plugin... I already expected the footer to work like that but could not find the translation in the string translation page.

Comment: Probably you got this solved but I am thinking that maybe the footer text is not translation ready. if you are using a child-theme (recommended if you want to modify the theme's code) you can make the string translation ready with this function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/. 

Basically enclose the text with _(), the first string is the text, the second the theme's text domain (you can find that on the style.css file's header).

Comment: I didn't solve this yet. (I'm not really sure how I did this. I would need to ask my customer for this). But thank you for the answer :)